# NameError: name 'count_vehicle' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, class

I want to call a function nested inside an outer function but an error is raised.

Problem: If the owner of the vehicle is a "VIP", then toll amount need not be collected but number of vehicles should be updated.
For any other type of owner, calculate the toll amount and update the number of vehicles.

```py
class Tollbooth:
    count = 0
    def init(self):
        self.__no_of_vehicle=0
        self.__total_amount=0
        
    def get_no_of_vehicle(self):
        return self.__no_of_vehicle
    
    def get_total_amount(self):
        return self.__total_amount
    
    def calculate_amount(vehicle_type):
        if(vehicle_type == "Car"):
            self.__total_amount = 70
        elif(vehicle_type=="Bus"):
            self.__total_amount =100
        elif(vehicle_type == "Truck"):
            self.__total_amount=150 
        else:
            self.__total_amount=70
        return self.__total_amount
    
    def count_vehicle(self):
        Tollbooth.count+=1
        return Tollbooth.count
    
    def collect_toll(self,owner_type,vehicle_type):
        if(owner_type=="VIP"):
            count_vehicle(self)
        else:
            count_vehicle(self)
            calculate_amount(vehicle_type)
            
T1=Tollbooth()
T1.collect_toll("VIP","Car")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot of things wrong.

- The `init` method should be called with double underscores.
- Anytime you want to access a member variable or method of your class you need to use `self`. The error shows the variable does not exist, because to call it you need to use `self.count_vehicles`.
- `self` also needs to passed as the first argument of all the methods, which I see you forgot to do later.
- When calling a method you don't need to pass `self`. It gets passed automatically

As @Spooked Husky said, I highly suggest you to read the [Python Class Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

So after fixing your code, this is the final working code

```
class Tollbooth: 
        count = 0 
        def __init__(self): 
            self.__no_of_vehicle=0 
            self.__total_amount=0

        def get_no_of_vehicle(self):
            return self.__no_of_vehicle

        def get_total_amount(self):
            return self.__total_amount

        def calculate_amount(self,vehicle_type):
            if(vehicle_type == "Car"):
                self.__total_amount = 70
            elif(vehicle_type=="Bus"):
                self.__total_amount =100
            elif(vehicle_type == "Truck"):
                self.__total_amount=150 
            else:
                self.__total_amount=70
            return self.__total_amount

        def count_vehicle(self):
            Tollbooth.count+=1
            return Tollbooth.count

        def collect_toll(self,owner_type,vehicle_type):
            if(owner_type=="VIP"):
                self.count_vehicle()
            else:
                self.count_vehicle()
                self.calculate_amount(vehicle_type)

T1=Tollbooth() 
T1.collect_toll("VIP","Car")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about how `self` is used. As far as I know, `self` is used to specify scope to a specific class, so you shouldn't be using `self` as parameter of a function.

Assuming you are using Python 3, have a look at [Python Class Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see the code is about the Tollbooth class, it just got messed up in the formatting. And they have used `self` the correct way

Comment: What I meant was `count_vehicle(self)` within the function `collect_toll`. I myself have never seen it used this way.